# Authorize.net or Paypal Adjustment of funds

Tags: php, api, authorize.net

A client of mine wants to have the capabilities that follow below.

1. End User Signs into application
2. End User Makes a Purchase for $X dollar amount
   --The Amount is then validated and captured to authorize.net
   --Authorize.net purchase order has been saved
3. within 30 days Client Logs back Into application and the order amount
   --The application then adjust the order amount

So in a nutshell, is it possible to submit a order to authorize.net and then go back in the future and adjust the amount on the same order after the money is at least held or captured. ??

I would like to know specifically for authorize.net but if there is another payment gateway that does so then let me know. thanks

Comment: If Authorize.net cannot accomplish this, could you save the dollar amount on your end, then adjust it and validate it on A.Net's end when they log in again?

Comment: See this is the problem. The client wants to have the money in his back account. Weird I know, but this is what he wants. He has to have the money possessed by him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a function of the payment gateway but a function of the merchant account. You can submit an amount to be charged against a credit card and receive an authorization number from the merchant account. That authorization number is valid for 30 days. You can then "capture" the full amount *or less* by submitting the authorization number to the processor. You cannot capture an amount more then was authorized.

If you want to charge more then was originally authorized you will have to process a new transaction for the new amount. If you do not want, or cannot get, the customer's credit card to charge a higher amount you have two options:

1. When you first authorize the credit card, authorize the highest amount you may need to capture later. This is not recommended as it freezes funds on the user's card and may cause them issues with making purchases elsewhere.
2. Use a system that allows you to store credit card information and then charge against it later. This would be a function offered by a payment gateway like Authorize.Net. Specifically their [Customer Information Manager (CIM)](http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/). Basically you create a payment profile for the customer and then when you need to charge them at a future date you charge against that profile.

Comment: Thanks john. Can I create profiles and store the credit card information to the profile via API ??? And then initiate a credit card transaction later ??

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what that API is for.

Answer (score 1):

An excerpt from the [Advanced Integration Guide](http://www.authorize.net/support/AIM_guide.pdf) (*Pg. 12*) from Authorize.Net

> **Authorization and Capture**
>
> This is the most common type of credit card
>   transaction and is the default payment  gateway transaction type. The
>   amount is sent for authorization, and if approved, is  automatically
>   submitted for settlement.

I think you are looking for the following:

> **Authorization Only**
>
> This transaction type is sent for authorization only. The transaction
>   will not be sent for  settlement until the credit card transaction
>   type Prior Authorization and Capture (see  definition below) is
>   submitted, or the transaction is submitted for capture manually in 
>   the Merchant Interface. For more information about capturing
>   Authorization Only  transactions in the Merchant Interface, see the
>   Merchant Integration Guide at 
>   http://www.authorize.net/support/merchant/. If action for the
>   Authorization Only transaction is not taken on the payment gateway 
>   within 30 days, the authorization expires and is no longer available
>   for capture. A new  Authorization Only transaction would then have to
>   be submitted to obtain a new  authorization code.

It does not appear you are allowed to adjust the already authorized transaction. You will need to authorize a new transaction with the adjusted dollar amont.